# Rename a file im saving and downloading as a pdf for Sql Server Reports?

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

i have the below code:

```
    var OrdID = screen.OrderRequest.OrderID;
    window.open("http://tempserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCustomerOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=" + OrdID + "&rs:Format=PDF");
```

this code is on a button that opens the file from the **temp** **server** and saves it as a **PDF**. it currently saves it as the name "CustomerOrder".. my question is, is it possible to rename the file using javacript to say 200 (being the order number)

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with JavaScript. There are many other questions on Stack Overflow asking the same thing!

Comment: seen a few but not the way im doing it, always worth a try :) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the C# parameter however, example below:

var theURL = "http://ReportServer/ReportServer_MYSERVER/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fPurchaseOrder&rs:Command=Render&OrderID=100&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=PDF";

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

byte[] myDataBuffer = Client.DownloadData(theURL);
```

this code above enables any SSRS report to be downloaded as a byte array. This then means that it can be saved in a specified location, with a name of your choice:

```
var filename = "Test.PDF";
var fileStructureLocal = "C:\\Test";
var fileStructureNetwork = "\\\\NetworkDrive\TestFolder";

var fileLocation = fileStructureNetwork + "\\" + filename;

 if (System.IO.File.Exists(url) == true)
        {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
 else
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(url, myDataBuffer);
            //SAVE FILE HERE
        }
```

this next block is how you rename the file, and specify the location. I have also added a check to see if it already exists, if it does it simply does nothing.

I hope this helps as this is something I have been trying to get working for a long time!